# Having trouble creating Randomly sequenced images from multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I've created a working javascript array random sequence generator detailed below. I am trying apply this same principle but have images in the array read from a folder.

I've tried to implement a version of

`document.getElementById("~ /images/demo.png")`, no luck

I'm not sure if this is the best approach. I'm satisfied with the text array functionality how do I replicate this with imagery (jpegs,gifs,etc.)? CSS can take a backseat right now.

In one line, how can I modify my current code to randomly sequence images from arrays from a given folder? Just inputting file names doesn't work i.e. `var firstSection = ["Bright.jpg ","Clear.jpg","Open.jpg"];` just returns the text string.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```js
function makeAseq() {
  /* First section in sequence  */  
  var firstSection = ["Bright ","Clear","Open"];
  /* second section in sequence  */  
  var secondSection = ["Foreground", "Growth", "Hard "];
  /* third section in sequence  */  
  var thirdSection = [ "form", "coloful", "slow",];

  firstSection = firstSection[Math.round(Math.random()* (firstSection.length-1))];
  secondSection =  secondSection[Math.floor(Math.random()*(secondSection.length))];
  thirdSection = thirdSection[Math.floor(Math.random()*(thirdSection.length))];                                 
  
  document.getElementById("holdSequence").innerHTML = "<div                style='background-color:#fff; opacity: .75;'> "+ firstSection + ","+ secondSection + ","+ thirdSection + "</div>"
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title> Section Sequence Generator </title>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Sequence Generator</h1>
    <p><button onClick="makeAseq()">Generate</button></p>
    <div id="holdSequence"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your code sample, you are missing `*` between `Math.random()` and `(firstSection.length-1))`

Comment: made the update, thanks for the catch

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeAseq() {

/*     First section in sequence  */  

var firstSection = ["demo3","demo1","demo2"];
var secondSection = ["demo3","demo1","demo2"];




 firstSection =    firstSection[Math.round(Math.random()*   (firstSection.length-1))]; 

secondSection =    secondSection[Math.round(Math.random()*(secondSection.length-1))];  



document.getElementById("holdSequence").innerHTML =
"<div style='background-color:#fff; opacity: .75;'>  <img src=\"/Users     /images/JPEG/"  + firstSection  +  ".jpg\"><img src=\"/Users/images/JPEG/"   + secondSection  +  ".jpg\"></div>"









}
```